# Why the need for a negative margin top in this case

Tags: html, css

Working on a project, did some standard inline block elements. To get the count display to the right area I had to put in a negative margin-top. I'm not sure why it wouldn't just position there on it's own accord. Is it because the count title is taking up an area or something else? I'd like to know why I had to do that and if there's a better way to avoid having to do that in the future or if I did it right and how to identify what happened so I can make sure I do it the same way in the future.

https://jsfiddle.net/ybh9qz37/

```
.count-display {
    height: 35px;
    width: 65px;
    background: black;
    color: red;
    display: flex;
    float: left;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
//why is this needed
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-family: Orbitron, sans-serif;
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

Comment: your `strict-button` class is having a good amount of height due to which the `count-display` got shifted downwards. Hence you have to add negative margin.

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding inline-block but shouldn't that not matter since the strict button is on the right? Or am I visualizing it incorrectly

Comment: it is not about the inline-block it is about float just refer my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to organize any `div` with a lot of divs is to group subdivs.

For example, in your case you have **3 subdivs** with different height going one under another. This causes a lot of problems, you should use this schema:

```
<div class="row2">
    // your left side div
    <div class="left" style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;">
        <span class="count-title">Count</span>
        <span class="count-display"><p>00</p></span>
    </div>
    // the right way is to create here <div class='right'> with similar styles as left        
    <span class="strict-button">
        <a rel="external" href="#button" class="button">Strict</a>
        <span></span>
    </span>

</div
```

And change your `.count-title` to :

```
.count-title {
    display:block;
}
```

This way you can easily extend your stucture in future without problems and save it organized

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better know how the float works and you will get the reason why you require a negative margin in your case.

You can refer this I hope that you will get a better understanding of the issue
[Everything You Never Know about css float](http://designshack.net/articles/css/everything-you-never-knew-about-css-floats/)